# Add CSS based on top-level parent page in WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress, parent

I've got a site with a deep page hierarchy, like so:

Parent
-Page 1
--Page 2
---Page 3

I need to be able to assign CSS to every page under "Parent", but of course WordPress only adds the parent page ID to the body tag of the parent page directly above the child, not the root parent. Any suggestions on achieving this?

Comment: You could use `get_ancestors()` to echo the parent ID into the class of the body. https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_ancestors

Comment: Yeah, I saw that and thought it might work. Any idea what that code would look like and where to add it? My programming skills lack a certain...they suck.

Comment: Something like this should do it: `</head>

<?php
$class = '';
if( is_page() ) { 
 global $post;
 $parents = get_post_ancestors( $post->ID );
 $id = ($parents) ? $parents[count($parents)-1]: $post->ID;
        $parent = get_post( $id );
 $class = $parent->post_name;
}
?>

<body <?php body_class( $class ); ?>>` https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_ancestors

Comment: Added that code but didn't see any additional classes.

Comment: Where did you add it? Should be in your header.php

Comment: That's where I added it. Here's what it looked like on my side:
http://pastebin.com/JbeE3NNN

I also tried this: http://pastebin.com/nUMT4czA But that had no effect, either. Thanks!

Comment: Any further suggestions, Gavin? I appreciate your help!

Comment: Sorry - inbetween jobs at the moment, so haven't had any time. I'll take a look this weekend.

Comment: My bad, Gavin. Your code worked; I was looking for a parent-page-ID class and it added the slug. Thanks again!